# How to find specific string text within direct .class file or .class file inside various jar file which are kept inside several sub-directories

Tags: java, shell, unix, awk

My worries about `System.out.println` used in java code, all java files are not available for me. We have only .class in Production. There are thousand files having `System.out.println` entry.
In order to clean this string. How can I find all culprit class files which has this string.
I know javap, which disassemble the .class file. But don't know if javap can be used for my purpose.
Any Unix command or java programme or awk script or known UI tool will work for me.
I just want to get rid of `System.out.println`

I used below command in cygwin but no success !

```
find . -iname '*.class' -printf "%p | grep -q 'System.out.println' && echo %p\n" | sh
```

Comment: what is your goal? de-compile all class files and do change on the source (removing System.out.println) and compile them ? then you can decompile, and import into an IDE

Answer (score 2):

I am using Gnu grep version 2.10.

Then given a sample class file wich contatin `System.out.println` i get

```
bash$ grep 'System.out.println' sample.class
Binary file sample.class matches
```

so in order to extract the files with matches you could use something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nocaseglob
files=(**/*.class)

for (( i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    file="${files[$i]}"
    res=$(grep 'System.out.println' $file)
    [[ $? == 0 ]] && awk '{print $3}' <<< "$res"
done
```